# Order of magnitude of few statements in apriori analysis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

If we have following statements in loops,

1. n = n/3
2. n = n-1
3. n = n-2

I want to know if we have the above statements what are their orders of magnitude and then how to write their big O notation?

I searched for these statements on Google, but I didn't get any good result. If you have any link for this please refer to me.

Comment: The definition of bigO @ wiki is all you need. I'm just saying this, because everyone asking about bigO here seem to skip this.

Comment: Are these supposed to be recurrence relations? If so, you have 1. log3(n) => O(log(n)) 2. O(n), and 3. O(n).

Comment: @rationalcoder I have edited my question. Please see.

Comment: It doesn't look like you changed anything important. Having those statements in loops doesn't mean much. Are they recurrence relations? Or, do you have three, nested loops that have those run times?

Comment: Actually, just add the pseudo code, so there is no guesswork.

Comment: My problem with this question : it reads like a homework dump. Pimped with bounty, but zero evidence of the op putting in any thoughts himself.

Comment: Is there a bug or how is it possible that Amar had 101 points or 51 with only 2 questions, 1 upvote each and several downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

### I. A bit of telepathy

Let`s assume all loops look like this:

```
n = <initial value>;
while (n >= 1) {
    <insert statement here>;
}
```

### II. Space complexity

All these loops have space complexity of `O(1)`.

Why? Because neither the RAM nor disk space these loops occupy while executing depend on the value of `n`.

### III. Time complexity

#### 1. `n = n / 3`

It is obvious that at `k`-th loop iteration, `k ≥ 1`, the resulting value `n'` shall become `n' = n / 3^k`.
So to find `k`, we are to solve the equation:

```
1 = n / 3^k    =>
3^k = n        =>
k = log3(n) = log(n) / log(3)
```

As long as `1 / log(3)` is a finite constant, the final answer is `O(log(n))`.

#### 2. `n = n – 1`

This is the easiest case of three.

For `n = 1` there is only 1 loop iteration, for `n = 2` there are two, and so on. `O(n)`.

#### 3. `n = n – 2`

For `n = 1` and `n = 2` the number of iterations is 1, for `n = 3` and `n = 4` it equals 2, and so on. Thus, `k = ⌈ n / 2 ⌉`.

`O(⌈ n / 2 ⌉) = O(n / 2) = O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

The three statements are O(1), as they are mere arithmetic operations on scalar variables.

Comment: Due to the triviality of the answer, it is likely that the original question is ill-formulated.